# How to make a 30days chart responsive on mobile using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, responsive, react-chartjs-2

I made a chart that included 30 days of absent data and I made it using the react-chartjs-2 library but the results are not responsive how to make it responsive?

this is what it looks like on a laptop:
[chart on laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjhmG.png)

and this if it looks on mobile:
[chart on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VIky.png)

this is my code:

```
  this.state = {
  loadFirst: true,
  loadData: false,
  filterYear: moment().format('YYYY'),
  filterMonth: moment().format('MM'),
  filtered: {
    year: moment().format('YYYY'),
    month: moment().format('MM')
  },
  data: {},
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this:

```
<Bar data={data} options={options} />}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"?

Comment: i want my chart data in the form of bars to remain visible at mobile size, or how to make it scroll?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to how small you can go because chart.js still needs to draw it, you can disable the legend while on mobile to give the chart a bit more space to work with since its taking up most of the canvas or you can increase the size of the canvas

Comment: thanks for the advice, I've done adding the width and making the overflow to auto.